# Cannot find reflection information on Router

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart, angular2-routing

I'm building a small sample app with angular2-dart and I'm getting an error while setting up routing:

*EXCEPTION: Cannot find reflection information on Router*

There is a button in my template that calls the logout method. The app crashes with the error when clicked.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';


@Component(
  selector: 'home',
  directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
)


class Home {
  Router router;

  Home(Router _router) {
    this.router = _router;
  }

  logout() {
    this.router.parent.navigate(['/Login']);
  }
}
```

I've read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/wiki/Angular-2-Dart-Transformer#dependencies) part of the angular wiki but I'm not sure how this relates to built-in packages. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `providers: const [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` to the @Component solved this.